# Test interdependent shiny module server functions

Tags: r, testing, shiny, testthat

I want to test the server function of a shiny module via `shiny::testServer()`. This module, lets call it module "Two", is dependent on another shiny module called module "One".
My problem is that I don't know how to access the return value of module "One", when testing module "Two".

*Example*

Testing module "One", which is independent works like charm:

```
library("shiny")
library("testthat")

moduleOneServer <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        myreactive <- reactive({input$name})
        hiName <- renderText({paste("Hi", myreactive())})
        hiName
    })
}

test_that("Test moduleOneServer", {
    testServer(moduleOneServer, {
        session$setInputs(name = "Liza")
        expect_equal(session$returned(), "Hi Liza")
        
        session$setInputs(name = "Frank")
        expect_equal(session$returned(), "Hi Frank")
        
    })
})
```

When trying to test module "Two" I need to access the return value of module "One". The following does not work (maybe my `moduleTwoServer` syntax is also wrong...):

```
moduleTwoServer <- function(id, name) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            req(name())
            plot(x=1, y=1, main = name())
        })
    })
}

test_that("Test moduleTwoServer", {
    testServer(moduleTwoServer,
               args = list(name = moduleOneServer("name")), {
                   output$plot # Test existance of plot
               })
})
```